# Foreign key error. Using excel and no errors appear

Tags: excel, foreign-keys, concatenation

I am attempting to import to the back end of a website. My two two tables are for this instance are IND and IO. I am attempting to import IO. IO has foreign key references to IND in fields State, code, and id.

First, am I correct in thinking that some 3-field combo of state, code, and Id is in IO but not IND?

Second, I put both in excel. I make sure that no leading zeros are dropped and then concatenate across the 3 fields to make it a unique string. From there, I do a match function. This tells me that all strings/combos in IO are found in IND.

Any other ideas on how to uncover items that are not in IND but in IO but yet seemingly do not show up using a method I have successfully used dozens of times?

Comment: The individual element of state, code, and Id all match up as well. So as of yet, all elements in IO are found in IND both individually and as a combination.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer. When I would extract the data in excel form, all of the values were there. When I would preview it, some were missing. I will take this up with those that run the server.